# MVC Framework and DB Connection

Tags: php, sql, model-view-controller, pdo

I have a RegisterModel.php, LoginModel.php etc etc and I repeat the same database code

```
public function connect(){

    if(!isset(self::$connection)){
        $config = parse_ini_file('config.ini');
        self::$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', $config['username'], $config['password'], $config['dbname']);
    }

    if (self::$connection === false){
        echo "Connection failed: ". self::$connection->connect_error;
    }

    return self::$connection;
}

public function query($query){


    // Connect to the database
    $connection = $this->connect();

    // Query the database with the functions below.
    $result = $connection->query($query);

    return $result;
}
```

I am moving to PDO connectivity and I was wondering if it's possible for my Model Class's to extend to a new class that I create with database connectivity. So for example... I will create

```
  class RegisterModel extends dbCore {

  }
```

Am I right in thinking this way would stop me from copying and pasting code on each class and make PDO connectivity usable on all classes that have it extended? Just want to verify if that is the correct way of doing things.

Comment: A model should not extend the db class. A model should only contain data

Comment: @Jens Where would I hold the database connectivity logic? Would it be the controller passing that to the Model?

Comment: The controller or better in a data access object (dao)

Comment: @Jans you're the best! I did some reading and that seems to be the best method. I now call the dao on my models. Am I right in saying that this is so I can easily change my database settings / way of connecting under one file and it alters for all them?

Comment: Yes you are Right.